# Apple Watch - Can I record "taptic" feedback to replay it on the same device?

Tags: iphone, apple-watch, ios8.2

**How can I record Taptic feedback on a user's Apple watch and replay it later?** In the videos that I saw the feedback was sent from one watch to another, meaning it is encoded and can be replayed.

Can taptic feedback be sent between watchkit apps?

Comment: Are you referring to the taps that a friend does that show up on the other person's watch? That's not taptic, those are just taps.

Comment: I was under the impression that the vibration/taps on iWatch is more customizable than on iPhone and wanted to see how such can be recorded and delivered later

Answer (score 1):

There’s currently no API in WatchKit to provide haptic feedback other than the one that happens when the user gets a notification. You might be able to do a crude pattern using a series of closely-timed UILocalNotifications, but I wouldn’t count on it. If you’d like the ability to do that in a future version of WatchKit, you should [file an enhancement request](http://bugreport.apple.com).